# Github pages isn't loading my Vue project assets

Tags: vue.js, github-pages

In my style.css inside my src/ folder, I have the following code:

```
background-image: url("./assets/background.jpg");
```

The background image is appearing when I host locally, but when I host it in Github Pages, the background image seems not to be loading.

The weird part is that the webpage is able to find the image path (clicking inspect element) as showed in the following image:
[background image does exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJKsz.png)

I would appreciate any help. Happy coding!
[Gihub Page](https://aneks1.github.io/brainfuck-interpreter/)
[Repo](https://github.com/Aneks1/brainfuck-interpreter)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have just to set the background on the body.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: It works when doing that, but the problem is that when I run my app before build, it works without putting the image on the body.

Comment: Don't worry, solved. For any reason, when built, Vue was setting opacity to 1% when it was supoposed to be 50%